# Meteor Mongo equivelent of SQL "field = field + 1"

Tags: mongodb, meteor

What is the mongo equivalent to this sql query

```
UPDATE table SET field = field + 1
```

Trying to update a simple views counter, sql can do it in one query, can mongo do it like this as well?

Answer (score 1):

See below, make sure you set the option of `multi` to `true` so that you update all records.

```
const table = new Mongo.Collection('table')

table.update( { }, { $inc: { field: 1 } }, { multi : true } );
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out

```
    Documents.update({"id": key},{  $inc: { views: 1 }  } );
```